# MATLAB Java Errors, Can't Save Data

Tags: matlab

I'm running an xPC target system for a low speed wind tunnel. At the end of a three hour test, MATLAB threw an exception that it couldn't save the data. I'm now getting class def errors like this for everything I try to click or do in the GUI (this is just one example). The command 'ver' is the only thing that seems to work. This means I can't save my data, which I really need. I would normally just restart MATLAB, but that will lose all my data!

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mathworks/widgets/grouptable/EditOnClickHandler$4 
at com.mathworks.widgets.grouptable.EditOnClickHandler.setEnabled(EditOnClickHandler.java:130) 
at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.widgets.table.FileTable$4$1.run(FileTable.java:188) 
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please help, I need this data as quickly as possible! Thanks!

Comment: Ouch. Sounds like a low level problem, like PermGen in Matlab's embedded JVM filling up, or Matlab encountering a serious I/O error and unable to read from its disk (like losing connectivity to a network filesystem). Is the command line working for basic operations? You may be able to write out the data from there, especially if you stick to functions that are already loaded in memory and/or do not depend on Java. Do `save()` or `fopen()` work at this point?